# Get promise is not being met with a Then function

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I'm having some issues with my first emberjs application. It is a sample application that contains users and notes for each user that they can update. I'm trying to do unit tests right now, so that I know the format for accessing information from the store, but I'm getting some errors when I try to access the notes from the user model. Here is the code:

```
testUser.get("notes").then(notes => {
   assert.equal(notes[0], testNote, "Note is valid."); 
});
```

And here is the error:

```
testUser.get(...).then is not a function
```

From what I read on emberjs.com the .get(...) function returns a promise that can then be used with a .then for access different elements in the array. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Also, is testUser one of your models?

Comment: testUser is created from the user model.

Comment: For some reason I am on 1.13.13, I bet that's it.

Comment: How do I get it to update?

Comment: `.get`ing a relationship only returns a promise if the relationship is asynchronous, is that the case?

Comment: `1.13.13` is probably your Ember **CLI** version. Your Ember and Ember Data versions are inside `bower.json`.

Comment: So, how do I update my ember then? It is at 1.13.11

Comment: For somebody to help you with this you need to show more, especially how the notes and user model looks like. And also what Ember and Ember Data versions you have installed (which can be seen in the console when the app first starts, or if you have Ember Inspector installed then you can find it there under the "Information" tab)